# How do I get the selected object's distance from the camera?

Tags: units, audio

I need to precisely visualize one object's distance in order to properly tune 3D sound properties. How can I measure the distance between me (the camera) and said object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the distance between two objects in the scene :

- setup a driver with the following settings

  - type : Scripted Expression
  - expr : var
- add new variable 'var' of type **Distance**
- set the targets to the objects of interest
- Now the driver value is the distance between these two object

[image]

Comment: This was flagged as low quality, can you add more to it. As it is your answer would be useless without the image.